# "All", "everybody", "everyone" to indicate all attendees of an event

Tags: word-choice

Which words (all, everybody, everyone) can be use to indicate in a timetable that all the attendees of an event are expected to contribute to a certain activity? For example:

Time |   Activity     | Speaker

8 am | Presentation 1 | Prof Brown

9 am | Presentation 2 | Prof Winter

10 am | Round table    | All/everybody/everyone

Comment: They're all possible; if you want to sound ultra-formal (and confuse everybody), you could use 'plenum'. 'All' sounds like a happy medium.

Comment: "All" is what would be used in a business setting as it's the most succinct. Business communication values succinctness above all. You should know, though, that that doesn't say that the activity is targeted to all the attendees but says that all attendees will be the speaker. Professor Brown isn't the target of "Presentation 1." He's the "speaker." The attendees are the target. Professor Winter isn't the target of "Presentation 2." He's the "speaker." The attendees are the target. So, "All" after "Round Table" says everyone will be the speaker-- expected to speak or at least contribute.

Comment: EdwinAshworth and Nancy, thank you for the comments that are answers indeed. @Nancy, I have changed the question to be more clear about the target/presenter.

Comment: If everyone is participating: all attendees.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had only heard the gaseous definition before, that's interesting!